# Does a huge /system/logs/error.txt file affects Opencart's functionality?

Tags: opencart

I have an old (forgotten) **Opencart v.1.5.6.1** installation with a huge `/system/logs/error.txt` file (3GB).

Does this huge error.txt file affects Opencart's functionality? I mean making the e-Shop slower somehow.

Comment: Yes it can slow down your server writing to a large log file each time

Answer (score 1):

You should fix all the errors. As it may cause some functionality not to work depending upon it. And also if you try to open this file from admin panel i.e from `tools -> error logs`, then it might take too much time to open the log file. In newer version it will show you an error like

`Warning: Your error log file error.log is 3.00GB!`